# UpdateProgress fire after first panel update

Tags: c#, panel, progress

I have an UpdateProgress associated with an UpdatePanel. The problem is it's not firing until the second update.

Ì have a general UpdatePanel with ID="uppGeneric" and a child one with ID="uppAgrupar" which has a LinkButton inside. When I click on LinkButton it doesn't fire the UpdateProgress bar.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uppGeneric" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12 mx-auto">
             <br />
             <asp:UpdateProgress ID="upCargando" DynamicLayout="true" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="uppAgrupar">
                  <ProgressTemplate>
                      <div class="progress">
                          <div class="indeterminate" style="width: 100%"></div>
                      </div>
                  </ProgressTemplate>
              </asp:UpdateProgress>
          </div>
       </div>

     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
             <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uppAgrupar" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                   <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAgrupar" runat="server" CssClass="el_s btn btn-info btn-block" OnClick="btnAgrupar_Click"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> (S) BUSCAR</asp:LinkButton>
                   </ContentTemplate>
                   <Triggers>
                      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAgrupar" EventName="Click" />
                   </Triggers>
             </asp:UpdatePanel>
         </div>
      </div>
```

And in code behind I execute (to be sure):

```
uppAgrupar.Update();
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: Normally an updateprogress is not contained within the content template of an updatepanel. Also, it appears you are nesting updatepanels. Do you really need to have them nested?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I removed "uppGeneric" but it's still not working at first. Even more, it doesn't fire at all. It's seems to fire (until second shot) when I update uppGeneric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a partial solution.

The UpdateProgress

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="upCargando" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="uppAgrupar">
                            <ProgressTemplate>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="indeterminate" style="width: 100%"></div>
                                </div>
                            </ProgressTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

generates the next HTML and CSS:

[image]

Which has "display: none;"

The problem is that display attribute was not set up to "display: block;" on first button click.

So, my solution was creating a javascript function that change the display attribute that is fired on the event "onClientClick".

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnAgrupar" runat="server" CssClass="el_s btn btn-info btn-block" OnClientClick="activar_barra()" OnClick="btnAgrupar_Click"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> (S) BUSCAR</asp:LinkButton>
```

and the javascript function is (it could access by ClientID but it's the same result)

```
    function activar_barra()
    {
        document.getElementsByClassName('progress')[0].parentNode.style.display = "block";
    }
```

Comment: It's only a partial solution because I shouldn't have to force the UpdateProgress to be shown. If I find a better solution, I will share it.

Comment: Another issue is that the solution depends on the "progress" class name. You have to be careful to not change that class and not add another element with this class. But it's working fine.